# What is best and rapid way for calculate this query?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm beginner in c# and linq ,write this query in c#:

```
var query1 = (from p in behzad.Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Centers
                         select p).ToArray();
            for (Int64 i = 0; i < query1.Count(); i++)
            {
                var query2 = (from tt in behzad.Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_DETAILs
                              where tt.fileid == FILE_ID && tt.code_markaz ==query1[i].code_markaz //"1215" //query1[i].code_markaz.ToString().Trim() //&& tt.code_markaz.ToString().Trim() == query1[i].code_markaz.ToString().Trim()
                              select new
                              {
                                  tt.id
                              }).ToArray();
                if (query2.Count() > 0)
                {
                    series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(query1[i].name_markaz, new double[] { query2.Count() }));
                    counter += 15;
                }


            }//end for
```

but up code is very slow,i have about 1000000 `Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Centers` and about 20 million record into the `Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_DETAILs` table,which is best query for up code?thanks.

Comment: _[Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?....No, it isn't the best place - though it is on-topic, there's a better place for such questions. You can take working code to Code Review - but do make sure to read their help center to see what exactly they expect from a good question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_

Comment: Here, or at CodeReview, you have to show more details. For one: what type of LINQ is this about? Also, what does the class model look like? Navigation properties?

Comment: query 1 has a ToArray, so you are bringing your whole 1,000,000 reconds into memory you need to combine the whole lot into one query using a join.

Comment: In your sample code you only seem to use the Count of that query2. Can't you just get that instead of all ids?

Comment: @tolanj how can i use best way for that?

Comment: @HansKesting yes,ه just want to know their number query2 count,is the best way for that?

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi - when you just use `select tt` and a `.Count()` instead of `.ToArray()`, the database will just return that count. A lot less data to get and transport! (`query2` will then contain that count directly). But still, a million queries will take significant time!

Comment: @HansKesting thanks.please write your solution in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code first gets a lot of records into memory, then executes a new query for each record - where you only use the count of items, even though you again get everything.

I think (untested) that the following will perform better:

```
var query = from center in behzad.Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Centers
    join details in behzad.Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_DETAILs
       on center.code_markaz equals details.code_markaz
    where details.fileid == FILE_ID
    where details.Any()
    select new { Name = center.name_markaz, Count = details.Count()};

foreach(var point in query)
{
    series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(point.Name, new double[] { point.Count };
    counter += 15;
}
```

- Instead of a lot of queries, execute just one query that will get just the data needed
- Instead of getting everything into memory first (with ToArray()), loop through it as it arrives - this saves a lot of memory

Comment: thanks,for answering my friend,please wait for test your solution.

Comment: in this line where details.Any() ,not know any()!,what happen?

Comment: Do you have a `using System.Linq` at the top of your file?

Comment: Or use `where details.Count() > 0` instead